# Formula Works in Google App Script Console, But Returns Authentication Error in Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-api

I have created a custom formula for one of my spreadsheets. It gets two Date parameters and returns the Total Unique Event count of a specific Google Analytics event. When I test my code, it works perfectly in the Google Apps Script. But when I try to use the same formula in the associated Spreadsheet, it causes the following error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to analytics.data.ga.get failed with error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. (line 13).

Here is my code:

```
var tableId = 'ga:78467590';

function test(){
  USE_CLICK_COUNT("2020-08-31", "2020-09-06");
}

function USE_CLICK_COUNT(startDate, endDate){ 
  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions':'ga:eventLabel',
    'filters':'ga:eventLabel=~^UseClick'
  };
  
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, 'ga:uniqueEvents', optArgs);
  Logger.log(results.getTotalsForAllResults());
  return results.getTotalsForAllResults();

}
```

When I run the `test()` function, it returns and logs `{ga:uniqueEvents=13}` - this is the number I'm looking for.

I have checked APIs and configuration details over and over again and can't figure out what I'm missing. Please see the attachments.

[image: Google Services settings of the script, 1]

[image: Google Services settings of the script, 2]

[image: Google Cloud Project association in script]

[image: Scope of the project]

[image: Credentials]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

I thought that your situation is the same with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205747). Unfortunately, in the current stage, Google APIs of Advanced Google services cannot be directly used with the custom function. Because the access token cannot be retrieved at the custom function. It seems that this is the current specification. So as the workaround for achieving your goal, it uses Web Apps created by Google Apps Script.

But I thought that the script of your question is a bit different from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205747). So when a sample script is proposed, it might be useful for you. So I would like to introduce the sample script for achieving your goal.

#### 1. Prepare script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save it.

Sample script:

```
// This is your script.
var tableId = 'ga:78467590';

function test(){
  USE_CLICK_COUNT("2020-08-31", "2020-09-06");
}

function USE_CLICK_COUNT(startDate, endDate){ 
  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions':'ga:eventLabel',
    'filters':'ga:eventLabel=~^UseClick'
  };
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, 'ga:uniqueEvents', optArgs);
  Logger.log(results.getTotalsForAllResults());
  return results.getTotalsForAllResults();
}

// I added below script.
const key = "samplekey"; // This is used as the key for running the Web Apps.

// Web Apps using as the wrapper.
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.key === key) {
    const res = USE_CLICK_COUNT(e.parameter.startDate, e.parameter.endDate);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(res));
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error.");
}

// This is used as the custom function.
function RUN_USE_CLICK_COUNT(startDate, endDate) {
  const url = `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}&key=${key}`;  // Please set the URL of Web Apps after you set the Web Apps.
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
}
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.

   - By this, the script is run as the owner.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.

   - In this case, no access token is required to be request. I think that I recommend this setting for testing this workaround.
   - Of course, you can also use the access token. But, in this case, when the access token is used, this sample script cannot be directly used as the custom function. So in this answer, I proposed to use the key for running the Web Apps script. But if you want to use the access token, I think that it will be achieved using PropertiesService.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
8. Please set the URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec` to `url` of above script. And please redeploy Web Apps. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. So please be careful this.

#### 4. Test this workaround.

Please put `=RUN_USE_CLICK_COUNT("2020-08-31", "2020-09-06")` to a cell. By this, the values of `"2020-08-31", "2020-09-06"` are sent to the Web Apps and the values from `USE_CLICK_COUNT` are returned.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Okay, well the authentication error is gone after applying this - but I got a new error. It's: "Text result of RUN_USE_CLICK_COUNT is longer than the limit of 50000 characters." I get the error in Spreadsheets

Comment: @mert dökümcü Thank you for replying. The error is due to the current specification. I apologize for this specification. But when `{ga:uniqueEvents=13}` is returned in your question, I think that the length is less than 50,000 bytes. How about this? So I'm worry about your settings might not be correct. So can you confirm it again? By the way, **when you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**.

Comment: I first deployed the script as web app with settings you gave, then copy-pasted the generated URL as you specified, then deployed as a new version. Did I do it correct?

Comment: @mert dökümcü Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when I install the Web Apps with the flow in my answer, I can confirm that the script works. I apologize for this. So for example, under your current situation, when you redeployed the Web Apps as new version again, what result will you obtain? If the situation is not changed, can you add your current script in your question? In that case, please replace the deploy ID of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec` as `###`. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I have done it as you specified. By the way, I am working on an organization (company) drive. Can this be the problem?

Comment: @mert dökümcü Thank you for replying. About `I am working on an organization (company) drive. Can this be the problem?`, I think that this might be the reason of your current issue. So as a test case, about the GAS project for deploying the Web Apps, can you test it using your personal Google account? When that is worked, it can be considered that the reason of your current issue is due to that.

Comment: Hi Mert. I have the same issue. Working on a company workspace and not able to access udf from the google sheet using bigquery api . Did you get up resolving this? Thanks